# Primeng Table Responsive Widths

Tags: primeng

Is there a way that I can set columns in a responsive table to have proportional widths, by that I mean a description column would be wider than a date column. Or is there a way that the table can set itself based upon the content being displayed? I have thought about setting percentage widths on each of the columns, but not sure that would be the best way of doing it.

Thank you.

Comment: Set `autoLayout` to true on the table. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it!
there is a sample project
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-width?file=src/app/app.component.ts

in the component file add  **width** in column definition:

```
 this.columns = [
      { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin', width: '10%' },
      { field: 'year', header: 'Year', width: '20%' },
      { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand', width: '15%' },
      { field: 'color', header: 'Color', width: '5%' }
    ];
```

in templet file use **[ngStyle]="{'width': col.width}**

```
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngStyle]="{'width': col.width}">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is actually what I am trying to avoid doing. What I would like to do is specify the default widths, and then if those widths are too wide for the display to then have them narrowed down proportionately. I have no idea if this is even possible, but it would be nice.

Comment: @dmoore1181 I know what you mean a have the same problem. If you find a solution please share.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `table-layout: auto;` for PrimeNG `table` element.
It works for me